# Fastest way to remove duplicates in list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a list of lists in Python3, where the data looks like this:

```
['Type1', ['123', '22'], ['456', '80']]
['Type2', ['456', '80'], ['123', '22']]
```

The list is quite large, but the above is an example of duplicate data I need to remove. Below is an example of data that is NOT duplicated and does not need to be removed:

```
['Type1', ['789', '45'], ['456', '80']]
['Type2', ['456', '80'], ['123', '22']]
```

I've already removed all the exact identical duplicates. What is the fastest way to accomplish this "reversed duplicate" removal in Python3?

Comment: I get that you want to remove duplicates, but can you please show us the desired output?

Comment: So, it appears you define "duplicate" as "having the exact same sublists but in any order", yes? So your first example is a duplicate because both type lines have `[123,22]` and `[456,80]` but in different order. The second is not a dupe because, though they both have `[456,80]`, the other sublists are different. Is that what you're getting at? Does the order matter *inside* the sub-lists (can `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` be considered identical sublists)?

Comment: Duplicate between which data you are looking for ? And if a duplicate value is found, what next ? Do you want to remove a sublist ? Or replace the duplicate number with zero ? Do you want to leave the duplicates what are found ? Do you want to leave the original on in `Type1` list or in `Type2` list ?

Comment: The duplicate would be removed if it's of Type1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Convert each sublist to a tuple and insert into a set.  Do the same for the compare candidate and compare sets to determine equality.
2. Establish a sorting method for the sublists, then sort each list of sublists.  This will enable easy comparison.

Both these approaches basically work around your problem of sublist ordering; there are lots of other ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['Type1', ['123', '22'], ['456', '80']],
    ['Type2', ['456', '80'], ['123', '22']]]
myList = []
for i in data:
    myTuple = (i[1], i[2])
    myList.append(myTuple)

print(myList)
for x in myList:
    for y in myList:
        if x==y:
            myList.remove(x)
            break

print(myList)
```